# Are single-lettered word models supported in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I cannot really pinpoint whether the issue is with Ember or Ember data, or if it's even an issue, but here's what happens:

Let's say you've got your model called `tell_me_a_story`. This will be the name that your JSON should provide, should you be using ActiveModelAdapter.

Regardless, when Ember or Ember Data process it internally, it'll camelize it and it becomes `tellMeAStory`, correctly indicating that "A" and "Story" are two separate words.

However, when internally it is decamelized to lookup for the model, the decamelize function will convert it into `tell_me_astory`.

This final behavior seems flawed to me, but when looking at the tests that derived this behavior, it is actually intended to manage acronyms in that fashion. (Compare the following example with the "innerHtml" that I would expect for camel casing multi-letter acronyms.)

```
QUnit.test("converts a camelized string into all lower case separated by underscores.", function() {
  deepEqual(decamelize('innerHTML'), 'inner_html');
  if (Ember.EXTEND_PROTOTYPES) {
    deepEqual('innerHTML'.decamelize(), 'inner_html');
  }
});
```

([Source in Ember Runtime](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/2c1f06a1d911aa0930ce0ef73a8d0186f3927dcf/packages/ember-runtime/tests/system/string/decamelize_test.js#L33))

So, **which is the correct way to use single-letter words in models with Ember? Are they even supported?**

---

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
// this comes from a separate data source, e.g. REST APIs
var myModelName = 'tell_me_a_story';
// this line will throw if the model file is named "tell-me-a-story"
if (!store.getById(myModelName, 1)) {
  // this line will throw if the model file is named "tell-me-astory"
  store.pushPayload(myModelName, myObject);
}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. I'd report it if I were you. Then again `innerHTML` would turn into `inner_h_t_m_l` which would be weird too :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the stores [`_normalizeTypeKey`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1950) then alter the camelCase behaviour to become what you want (e.g. dasherized or just fix this one case).

You can also override the serialisers [`typeForRoot`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest-serializer.js#L550) when going the other way - this lets you tell ember what the model key is (e.g. `tellMeAStory`) for a particular key in your data (e.g. `tell_me_a_story`).

It appears there is work underway to make everything work like the container does (which is dasherized)