# Ember: global mapping from typekey to model name coming and going

Tags: ember-data

The server API changed from using type keys of "foo" to "bar". My Ember app uses `foo` everywhere, and I don't want to change them all to `bar`. I see I can use `typeForRoot` to map root-level hash keys to a model name, but that appears only to apply to downloading. When I do a save on my Foo model, I want the PUT to be generated with a hash key of `boo` as well. Is there any simple way to completely map type keys to models, both coming and going?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I posted on [another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29543803/4631588) might help you..

Basically the function you need to look at is the stores `_normalizeTypeKey`.

> You can override the stores [`_normalizeTypeKey`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1950) then alter the camelCase behaviour to become what you want (e.g. dasherized or just fix this one case).
>
> You can also override the serialisers [`typeForRoot`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest-serializer.js#L550) when going the other way - this lets you tell ember what the model key is (e.g. `tellMeAStory`) for a particular key in your data (e.g. `tell_me_a_story`).
>
> It appears there is work underway to make everything work like the container does (which is dasherized)